# Sitecore WFFM - How to trigger a form externally

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a web forms for marketers, and I need to "run" that webform through code from somewhere else.

Is there a way to load the webform and run its execute action? For example with a regular sitecore item I can get it based on its ID, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to cast a regular sitecore item, to a WFFM item and then execute its save actions (and possibly set its fields).

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're scenario is here. But you could consider creating a WFFM save action of your own, and have that one speaking to your "somewhere else" code maybe?

Comment: No, because the scenario is the exact opposite. I already have a custom save action, and I need to trigger that custom save action from somewhere else, using the form (so that all of the sitecore form data is used in that call).

Comment: The particular use scenario is this: I have a sign up for newsletter web form and it works fine. However, I also need to make a "check here to sign up to newsletter", which is available during an order purchase confirmation screen (where the email address amongst other things, is available anyway).

When the customer then purchase an order, it should additionally run the form code and sign up to the newsletter that way.

Comment: Ok, I see. And there's no easy way to make the Order Confirmation page (or part of it) based on WFFM I take it?

Comment: You should probably point Reflector to the "Sign up for newsletter" save action in WFFM/ECM and see what it does. In reality it is little more than adding a user to a specific role for the mailing list.

Comment: What I've done in the past is have a regular external form action point to an external request handler (.ashx) that is then accessible to the server. This will allow the external form to be set up any way, and the data passed a long into the ashx file can be compared against the WFFM for server-side validation and if certain fields exist in Sitecore. Let me know if you'd like an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to insert data into the WFFM database without having to run through the WFFM submit action? Did I get that right?

If so, you could submit form code to the WFFM DB using the following code, and it would show up seamlessly in the report page of that form:

Say you have your list of fields populated in a list of this class:

```
public class WffmField
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string FieldGuid { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    }
```

the field guid would be the guid from sitecore:
[image]

You can then save to the WFFM database:

```
// This should be populated with the data you want to send to the WFFM database
var fields = new List<WffmField>(); 
var wffmDatabaseFields = fields.Select(GetWFFMDatabaseField).ToList();

Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataManager.InsertForm(
    formId: new Sitecore.Data.ID("<Form guid here>"),
    fields: new AdaptedResultList(wffmDatabaseFields),
    sessionID: AnalyticsTracker.SessionId,
    data: null);
```

Hope this helps!